# USB power issues on ASUS X550 laptop

Tags: laptop, usb

My ASUS X550 laptop seems to have, but I'm not sure, a current limit on USB ports, even when powered from the network. Take this as an example: the laptop has two usb ports (one is 3.0, but that doesn't seem to matter) and I usually keep a hub attached to it with a mouse, a keyboard and pendrives or whatever. Now, if I attach an external audio device (a focusrite scarlett which is, by the way, externally powered with its own adapter, or an usb midi controller) to the hub, the computer stops powering them. They are not detected anymore by the system and turn off completely. This also happens, for example, if I remove the hub completely and attach the mouse or keyboard to one port and the midi or audio device to the other.

My questions are:

1) Does anyone have more info about this, why it happens, and if it really is a current limit (but why does it happen on externally powered devices then?)

2) I considered buying an externally powered usb hub, but I'm not sure. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I would certianly try bumping up the quality of the USB hub. An externally powered one should not cost much, and will definitely be more reliable, especially for a laptop. Its not a limit based on specs; USB has allowed at least 127 devices per bus all the way back to 1.0. Note that power supplied to USB ports varies from box to box, but often also from port to port. most phone moders for instance insist on using a desktops rear USB ports, as they have more reliable power than the front-facing ports. I'd guess that laptop USB are more like the front ports than the rear, but thats just a hunch

Comment: USB 3.0 has a current limit, if your laptop only has 2 ports, it likely only has one internally one USB controller thus the number of devices you can connect will be limited based on their power requirements.  An external powered hub might help, but you will still be limited by the fact internally, you only have a single USB hub.  Front ports being more reliable has to do with cost to build, and not any technical reason,

Comment: Update: I got an external powered hub. It still doesn't work, but curiously enough, if I plug the audio interface in the new hub, windows says it's over the power limit and it won't work. This, with both the external power plugged in or not. If I attach the mouse and keyboard to the hub on one port of the laptop, and the audio interface to the other port, I get the same result as before, that is, the interface works, mouse and keyboard disappear. As I thought, it's not a matter of power but something in the usb controller (or even in the drivers)